# Conditional rewriting in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm rather new to the whole .htaccess thing and I'm using the following right now to use 'pretty url's':

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NS,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now i found my website a bit slow and decided to start gzipping my CSS files thru a php script I found somewhere on the web ([the website](http://www.wangarific.com/how-to-gzip-css-files/)). For this to work I need to rewrite the url to open the correct php file. That would look something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).css$ /csszip.php?file=$1.css [L]
```

But I only want the first to happen when the second doesn't and vice versa. In other words i'd like something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    if request doesn't contain .css do
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NS,L]
    else do
        RewriteRule ^(.*).css$ /csszip.php?file=$1.css [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone help me with the proper code or a place where i can find a way to use some kind of conditional statement in htaccess files?

Thanks in Advance!:)

Comment: if it doesn't have `.css` file then automatically doesn't go with csszip.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.css
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NS,L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*).css$ /csszip.php?file=$1.css [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also, you can put the last rule on top

Comment: After doing one RewriteRule will it cease to execute the following RewriteRules?